# Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox installed on OSX El Capitan

Tags: symfony, ubuntu, virtualbox, osx-elcapitan

I try to run Symfony on VirtualBox and use the Shared Folder from my El Capitan.
The OSX dictates the permission so when I try to have a shared folder I can't change the user for the app/cache and app/log folder which means Symfony can't write to those files. I tried also to change the permission to 777 both from the ubuntu box and from the Mac and in both ways Symfony fails to write to the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was after, but I remember in Symfony you can configure to have the cache and logs directory in a different location, so I moved it outside the shared folder.

The code is inside AppKernel.php

```
public function getCacheDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/../../symfony_var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
}

public function getLogDir()
{
    return dirname(__DIR__).'/../../symfony_var/logs'.$this->getEnvironment();
}
```